# How to post data to a sms server (if there is no internet) and then send back from the Sms server to the web server?

Tags: database, sms, twilio-api, clickatell

i'm building a mobile application that needs to send critical data to a remote database but it may have networks issue in some user's location. I want to know if it's possible wrap up the data in text message and then send a sms server and allow the sms server to post the data in the database.
If yes, do you have any Idea how to implement ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do this using Twilio in an Android application. You would do it by using Android APIs to send an SMS from the app using the device's SIM card (I believe this is possible, though I'm not an Android developer, I have seen it done before). You would send that SMS to a Twilio number that you had bought with your account.

When the Twilio number receives an incoming SMS, Twilio will take all the data about the SMS and package it up as an HTTP request that it sends to a URL you define. That URL should point at your web application and when your application receives the incoming HTTP request can read the data and store it in your database.

To understand more about the SMS to HTTP request flow, I recommend you follow the [tutorial on receiving and responding to SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply).

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a shot !